# ros_industrial_cmake_boilerplate/code_coverage.cmake:168 (message): lcov not found!

Tags: ros2

I'm trying to install TrajOpt to intergrate with the ROS2. I have download the tesseract_ros2 and all its dependencies from https://github.com/tesseract-robotics/tesseract_ros2 ,also the trajOpt_ros2 from https://github.com/Levi-Armstrong/trajopt_ros-2. But during building ,some error ocurr. See my terminal output below:

```
Starting >>> tesseract_command_language
--- stderr: tesseract_command_language                            
CMake Warning at /home/xxx/ws_moveit2/install/ros_industrial_cmake_boilerplate/lib/cmake/ros_industrial_cmake_boilerplate/code_coverage.cmake:156 (message):
  Code coverage results with an optimized (non-Debug) build may be misleading
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (initialize_code_coverage)
CMake Error at /home/xxx/ws_moveit2/install/ros_industrial_cmake_boilerplate/lib/cmake/ros_industrial_cmake_boilerplate/code_coverage.cmake:168 (message):
  lcov not found! Aborting...
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (initialize_code_coverage)
---
Failed   <<< tesseract_command_language [0.12s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< trajopt_common [0.22s]                                          
Aborted  <<< trajopt_sco [1.30s]                                             
Aborted  <<< bullet [4min 26s]**
```

How can i fix it and proceed? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

Please pay attention to the following error which you have reported above:

```
  lcov not found! Aborting...
```

Therefore, please install `lcov` on your Ubuntu machine using the following command:

```
sudo apt install lcov
```